# How to query mongo with multiple db ref relations

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb

Lets say I have following DB structure
I have **users** collection

```
"users": [
    {
      "_id": "4775222e-8e4f-4f84-8dba-b097291bbd39",
      "surname": "Smith",
      "forename": "John"
    }
  ]
```

I have **job_requests** collection that has a reference to users collection in 1 field like so:

```
"job_requests": [
    {
      "_id": "f4bdda3e-0e8d-4e8d-b070-7d01421f5a51",
      "description": "do something",
      "riskManager": {
        "$ref": "users",
        "$id": "4775222e-8e4f-4f84-8dba-b097291bbd39"
      }
    }
  ]
```

And finally I have **jobs** collection that has a reference to **job_requests** collection in 1 field:

```
"jobs": [
    {
      "_id": "someID",
      "description": "do something",
      "jobRequest": {
        "$ref": "job_requests",
        "$id": "f4bdda3e-0e8d-4e8d-b070-7d01421f5a51"
      }
    }
  ]
```

I need a query that will return all jobs by userId, which means I need to find all job_requests with that user, and then all jobs with those job_requests.
I tried with mongo aggregation on [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fh0Jc-mqvGE) and this works but only for mongo 4.4.1

```
db.jobs.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "job_requests",
      "localField": "jobRequest.$id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "jobRequest"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$jobRequest"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "jobRequest.riskManager.$id": "4775222e-8e4f-4f84-8dba-b097291bbd39"
    }
  }
])
```

And gives me correct result. Problem is that my server is 4.2.8 and on that version this produces error *'FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.'*
How can I make the query so it doesn't break on 4.2.8 ? I cannot restructure data, I need to have all these relations between collections. I might add, the back-end on top of this is spring data mongodb, so I can use those features to construct query, but I guess it boils down to javascript for mongo QL.

Answer (score 0):

As is suggested in this [blog post](https://dev.to/saurabh73/mongodb-using-aggregation-pipeline-to-extract-dbref-using-lookup-operator-4ekl) it can be done with using **$objectToArray**, **$arrayElemAt** and **$addFields** operator.

so it becomes something like

```
db.jobs.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "jobRequest": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$objectToArray": "$jobRequest"
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "jobRequest": "$jobRequest.v"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "job_requests",
      "localField": "jobRequest",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "jobRequest"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "jobRequest": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$jobRequest",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$jobRequest"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "jobRequest.riskManager.$id": "4775222e-8e4f-4f84-8dba-b097291bbd39"
    }
  }
])
```

Avoid DbRef at all cost when using mongo.